# Валиден ли самоподписанный сертификат для драйвера мини-фильтра на win7x64?

Tags: windows, windows-7, filter, драйвер, сертификат

Подходит ли самоподписанный сертификат для драйвера мини-фильтра файловой системы для работы на 64 битных системах (7, 8, 8.1)? Про 10, 11 явно указано, что требуется сертификация Code Signing EV + microsoft. Что касается, например, 7х64, не получается запустить службу драйвера на тестовой машине (через net start или sc start), Системная ошибка 577.

Системе Windows не удается проверить цифровую подпись этого файла. При последнем изменении оборудования или программного обеспечения могла быть произведена установка неправильно подписанного или поврежденного файла либо вредоносной программы неизвестного происхождения.

Проблема в моем сертификате (создавал по гайдам через signtool, добавлял сертификат в список доверенных издателей и доверенные корневые центры спецификации), или работа драйвера с самоподписанным сертификатом на 64 битных системах (включая win7x64, где нет secure boot) невозможна?

Comment: Я самоподписанные скртификаты для установки виртуальных дров virtio докидывал в `TrustedPublisher` и всё ехало ок. Вот это вот: https://github.com/don-rumata/ansible-role-install-virtual-guest-tools/blob/4fa180d24a04caefbe2004ee5855241696d03ad1/tasks/install-guest-tools-4-na-windows.yml#L40